# Capturing spaces with Scanner?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have a series of questions being asked to create a deck of flash cards. So far, I can gather questions and answers, provided the questions don't have spaces. If a question does have spaces, the answer is skipped, however if the answer has spaces, there is no problem. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    System.out.println("What is the question for number " + (cards + 1) + "?");
    question = in.next();
    System.out.println("What is the answer for number " + (cards + 1) + "?");
    answer = in.next();
```

And here is the resulting output with spaces in a question and an answer:

```
What is the question for number 1?
This is a question
What is the answer for number 1?
What is the question for number 2?
x
What is the answer for number 2?
This is an answer
What is the question for number 3?
X
```

Comment: Use a `Line` after `next`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `next()` method, use `nextLine()` to capture the entire line instead of just the next word:

```
System.out.println("What is the question for number " + (cards + 1) + "?");
question = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is the answer for number " + (cards + 1) + "?");
answer = in.nextLine();
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

next() reads the input only till the space. It can't read words separated by a space.

nextLine() reads input including space between the words (it reads till the end of the line)